# Как сделать прокрутку на сайте по якорю, чтобы блок отображался целиком

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, веб-дизайн

Всем доброго дня, у меня имеется навигация на сайте используя id и , но так как хедер у меня фиксированный сверху, выходит что при подходе к блоку, он занимает какую-то часть места и выглядит не очень красиво. Хотел бы узнать как можно решить данную проблему наиболее легким способом. Ниже привожу схему как выглядит навигация и блоки

```
        <nav class="nav_desktop col-8">
            <a class = 'nav_element' href="#about_us">Quiénes somos</a>
            <a class = 'nav_element' href="#our_team">Nuestro equipo</a>
            <a class = 'nav_element' href="#description">Servicios</a>
            <a class = 'nav_element' href="#price">Precios</a>
            <a class = 'nav_element' href="#reviews">Comentarios</a>
            <a class = 'nav_element' href="#contacts">Contactos</a>
        </nav>
        
        <div id = '#about_us'></div>
        <div id = '#our_team'></div>
        <div id = '#description'></div>
        <div id = '#price'></div>
        <div id = '#reviews'></div>
        <div id = '#contacts'></div>
```

[То как хочу чтобы выглядело](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M5PH.jpg)

[То как выглядит сейчас](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHsQy.png)

Comment: К вашему id примените стиль scroll-margin-top

Comment: не ответ , а скорее вопрос - может ли помочь если мы сделаем так: для хедера height 10vh а для блока min-height 90vh ? ,будет ли это работать ?

Comment: А действительно нельзя разве всему сектору идущему после меню, которое в display: fixed, задать margin-top в высоту навигации? Если она конечно эта высота не меняется.